# How to call a Rust function in C?

Tags: c, rust, function-pointers, ffi

The first "similar question" shown to me while posting this is called "How to call C function in Rust". This is the opposite of what I need.  Every tutorial I can find that technically does answer my question, only does so by exporting the Rust function in a DLL so a C executable can call it, using `extern "C"`.

But I have a Rust executable that is calling a C DLL function that takes a Rust function pointer as a parameter (I haven't actually written this C function yet).  Any basic examples demonstrating how to do this?  I've already got Rust calling some of the C DLL functions, but I need to write code for both Rust and C so that C can execute a Rust callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this C code compiled to a library named `lib.dll`, exporting a single function which accepts a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns nothing:

```c
__declspec(dllexport) void foo(void (*callback)()) {
    callback();
}
```

Then this Rust code will send the function `callback` to that C function.  Upon execution, it prints the line `"callback()"`:

```rust
extern "C" fn callback() -> () {
    println!("callback()");
}

fn main() {
    println!("main()");
    call_dynamic();
}

fn call_dynamic() -> Result<u32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new("lib.dll")?;
        let foo: libloading::Symbol<extern "C" fn(extern "C" fn()) -> u32> = lib.get(b"foo")?;
        Ok(foo(callback))
    }
}
```

You should see this in your console:

```
main()
callback()
```

I am on Windows and compiled the C code with this command:

```sh
gcc --shared lib.c -o lib.dll
```

The Rust code was run with this:

```sh
cargo run
```

Comment: I think you're missing about 3 `extern "C"`s

Comment: I removed them in an edit after finding the code worked without them.  If I am mistaken somehow feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: It is not needed to make the code compile, but it is needed to ensure ABI compatibility with C. `unsafe` is not required though because these functions are (presumably) not unsound to call. (`extern crate` is not needed at all anymore, since Rust 2018)